# Table View Controler with Static Cells issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static, tableview, cells

Very new to to all this. Using storyboard I created a Table view controller with a list of static cells. When I run it everything is fine but I just would like to be able to stop empty cells from appearing when I scroll to the end in the stimulator. I haven't created any extra cells and you see where it ends within storyboard.

I noticed when I switched the cells to dynamic cells and opened it up on the stimulator there was a definite top and bottom but all the cells appeared with no text at all.

I have created 15 scenes with the same issues so I am hopping it is easily resolved!

Thanks!
Cronan

Comment: I don't see these empty cells when I make a table view with static cells. You should provide more information on how you made the table view. How many extra cells do you see?

Comment: @rdelmar my mistake! What was i thinking? I have removed the answer now.

Comment: what does your [UITableViewDataSource "`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:) method look like?

Comment: @rdelmar When the cells are static text appears but when I switch then to dynamic then the text doesn't show up in the simulator. Within storyboard I created a table view controller. Then I switched the cells from dynamic prototypes to static and created enough cells to fill the scene for it to be necessary to have to scroll to view them all. When I run the simulator you can scroll them to the last cell I created but another THREE cells appear. So it just looks like an empty list after the last cell I created.

Comment: @michaelDautermann I know what your are looking for but I am not able to code at all yet. I have been only using storyboard to create everything thus far. So there isn't any code/method UITableViewDataSource "tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:" within my .h or.m files.

Comment: Visually it looks fine but from a practical point of view Im not too sure how it will effect or possibly limit working with my scene but within the table view attributes inspector I changed the style from plain to grouped and now there is a clear visual start and end when I run it on the simulator. That sound about right and is ok?? Sorry I couldn't explain my problem too well, I am on the biggest learning curve!

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered here [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666504/overlapping-cells-in-static-tableview-built-using-storyboard) Setting up **Auto Layout connections** from the label to the Content View solves this issue.