# Overlapping cells in static tableview built using storyboard

Tags: ios8, xcode6

All,

I'm using the Xcode 6 beta to build an iOS8 project using storyboard and swift. In the storyboard, I've created a Table View Controller as my primary view when the application loads and have added a label to the first cell and a label to the second cell.

The table looks fine in the storyboard, but when I run the application, the cells overlap. This is a brand new project with no other changes made or code added.

You can see both the storyboard and the running application in the photo below. Any ideas on what could be driving this?

Additionally, when I try to add a button to one of the cells, I get a grey box that covers 90% of the view.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've had this issue. Try making some Auto Layout connections from the label to the Content View of the cell, and from the table view (and its cells) to the containing view, to force the views to be the proper size.

The following worked for me.

1. Control-click and drag from your label to left side of the cell it's in. When the modal comes up, check the box for 'Leading Space to Container'.
2. Repeat the same Control-click and drag process for each side of the cell, selecting the relevant Auto Layout option when it appears.
3. (Optional) Try to Control-click and drag from your table view to the each side of the containing view (if there is one), and repeat the steps from above.

Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: Just ran into something very similar to this.  This solved my problem but I'm still trying to figure out if this is a bug or not.

Comment: Still having the same issue in XCode 6.0.1, it's driving me crazy! I can't use your solution because i'd prefer not to use auto layout for this project (planning on having the lower required iOS version possible). Any idea on how to do that without AL?

Comment: @dvkch Not really sure sorry. I thought the problem might have been caused by auto layout. You could try setting the cell's content view width and height manually.

Comment: Okay so I fixed it by editing the storyboard in XCode 5 (not the "Open in" option of xcode, I really launched XCode 5) because I noticed that if I modify my views in XCode6 then quit and reopen it it simply looses the frames...