# Static or Prototype UITableViewCell subviews are resized incorrectly in Storyboard on Xcode 6.1.1, iOS 8.1 SDK

Tags: uitableview, xcode6, uicollectionviewcell, autoresize, ios8.1

So I updated to **Xcode 6.1 earlier and 6.1.1 today**. I notice that there's an issue while using Static / Prototype UITableViewCell (or Prototype UICollectionViewCell) in Storyboard. All the subviews with certain Autoresizing masks will be resized incorrectly when running on device / simulator.

[image: UISlider as a subView of the Static UITableViewCell]

**UISlider as a subView of the Static UITableViewCell**

[image: Autoresizing rule is Flexible Width. Or Flexible LeftMargin also causes the problem.]

**Autoresizing rule is Flexible Width. Or Flexible LeftMargin also causes the problem.**

[image: Observing the Slider is too long, went off the screen the the right]

**Observing the Slider is too long, went off the screen the the right**

I already submitted a bugreport to Apple. Hope to receive a response soon.

Comment: Has anyone updated to Xcode 6.1.1 and used UICollectionViewCell yet?

Comment: happens the same.. solution on this??

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and have found a solution that works for me. It seems like Xcode is not (always) recording the initial frame sizes of table view cells and their content views.

If you open the storyboard in another editor (preferably with Xcode closed), and have a look at your cells you should find the following:

```xml
<tableViewCell ...>
   <autoresizingMask .../>
   <tableViewCellContentView ...>
```

A number of keys and attributes above have been omitted for brevity. What is missing from the above is `rect` keys for the `tableViewCell` and the `tableViewCellContentView`. Autoresizing relies on the initial frame size to determine offsets from the right/bottom. Without the initial frame size (given by the `rect` keys) the initial frame is calculated as 0,0,0,0 which doesn't affect items anchored to the top or left, but does (of course) affect items anchored to the right/bottom.

To fix the issue ensure there is a (correct) `rect` key for every `tableViewCell` and `tableViewCellContentView`, e.g.:

```xml
<tableViewCell ...>
   <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="44"/>
   <autoresizingMask .../>
   <tableViewCellContentView ...>
      <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="43"/>
```

If you have an accessory view enabled for a cell you might need to reduce the content view's width for that cell. The width / height shown in Xcode (greyed out) for the content view is what should be put in to the storyboard (by hand).

I should add that Xcode does not appear to remove these `rect` keys from the storyboard when editing, so after edits are complete the storyboard should still be entirely editable with Xcode.

Comment: This is an amazing find! Issue is also present on `<collectionViewCell>`.